# Leave a Pin on high after shutdown

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, relay

I was wondering if; I leave the power on my Rpi but shut it down. Could I leave a pin on high?

Would love to make a led go on as soon as the rpi shutsdown. I was wondering if I could do that without making a relay.

Comment: I think you are going about this backwards. You could wire a relay to be normally closed then on power up toggle the relay to an open state turning your LED off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike a PC, the Pi has no true "shutdown" where the power goes off completely.

What actually happens is that the system sets a flag in a special area of memory that survives a reset, and then goes through the reset. The GPU firmware then detects that flag and puts the system to sleep in a minimal-power consumption state.

Unfortunately, that means you can't control the state of the pins easily, or perhaps at all. If it's possible at all, it would be with a custom ["device tree blob"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/pin-configuration.md), though even that couldn't help you avoid the several seconds during which the state of all the pins are set to inputs with pull-ups or pull-downs, depending on their default state in the hardware, and you can't override that.  The custom DT blob approach could work only if this "sleep" state is entered *after* the blob is processed. I have no idea if it is but I suspect it's not.

The default state of all the pins at reset is documented on page 102 in the datasheet, linked under "Peripheral specification" of the [BCM2835](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/README.md) docs.

Answer (score 0):

The question did say without wiring a relay . One way would be to use a changeover switch to turn your Rpi on and off however I would recommend shutting the rpi down through a recognized shutdown process. The changeover switch would be a final power isolation after shutdown. There are of course other ways such as letting the pin go low and usingthat pin as the ov side . I'm sure with power left connected to the input a few of the pins stay with voltage .